# Increasing rows returned by "select top" suddently makes the query incredibly slower

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

A load that has been running in about 2 minutes suddenly turned into a 90 minute run before being manually cancelled.

It's a simple shadow query:

```
select fields
into shadow_table
from table
where date = '8/23/2011'
```

`date` has a non-clustered index on it.

If I change the query to select

- `top 300000` it completes in 2 seconds
- `top 400000` it runs in 3 minutes
- `top 500000` I got bored waiting and cancelled it

Our server team shows a lot of self blocking while it runs.

Can anyone suggest possible bottlenecks to look at?

Comment: Can you explain what 'self blocking' means?

Comment: It's running as spid 51 and is reporting blocked by spid 51

Comment: Is the wait_type CXPACKET? That is not a block, you need to follow trough and look at the subtasks to see what they're doing. See my updated post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Out of date stats.**

Self-blocking only occurs with parallelism, and super long parallel runs (compared to norms) ordinarily means out-of-date stats.  It could also be a change in cardinality in the data.

Step 1 should be running an `UPDATE STATISTICS WITH FULLSCAN` on your source table.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the proven [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc966413) methodology to identify the bottleneck.

When a request is running parallel query the proper way to analyze blockage is to dive at the subtask level and see what is blocking *each* of the sub tasks. One should never stop at `CXPACKET` as wait type, or 'self block' as an explanation.

```
select w.last_wait_type, 
    wt.wait_type, 
    wt.resource_description, 
    wt.blocking_session_id, 
    t.pending_io_count, 
    r.* 
from sys.dm_os_tasks t
left join sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks wt on wt.waiting_task_address = t.task_address
join sys.dm_os_workers w on t.worker_address = w.worker_address
join sys.dm_exec_requests r on t.session_id = r.session_id
where r.session_id = <queryspid>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's what it seems - an archival query - on records that won't be updated while it's running, you can turn off blocking entirely. Other queries that need integrity but use your records won't be affected - they manage their own locking.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have your fields as part of the include of your nonclustered index. If you don't, you're going to have to back to the table using an RID lookup to get that data.

```
create nonclustered index ix_whatever on YourTable (date) 
include (field1, field2, ...)
```

Comment: We're avoiding covering indexes on the majority of these tables since performance is acceptable. When it runs properly, a load time of 2 minutes is fine.